# If $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C},f(z)=\arg(z)$, the principal component of $z \in \mathbb{C}$ Find the explicit formula of $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis

If  $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C},\;f(z)=\arg(z)$, the principal component  of $z \in \mathbb{C}$  taking values in the interval $]-\pi, \pi]$. Write $f=u +iv$, finding the explicit formulas for $u$ and $v$?

Can I just say that since if $z=a+ib$ then $v=0$ since $f$ is a real valued function and $u=\arctan(b/a)$ since $\arg(z)$ is the angle made by the point $z$ with the $x$-axis?
Am I missing something or is there something more to this?

Comment: Indeed $u=\arctan(b/a)$ when $a>0$, but you'll need other cases for $a=0$ and the second and third quadrants.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. If $f$ is defined on $\mathbb C$, then $arg(z)$ must take values in $[-\pi.\pi)$ or $(-\pi,\pi]$. What about $z = 0$? Note that $f$ cannot be continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisely, $u=\text{atan2}(\frac ba)$.

It essence,

$$u(z)=
\begin{cases}
\text{arctan}\frac ba,&a\ge0 \\
-\pi+\text{arctan}\frac ba,&a<0, b<0\\
\pi+\text{arctan}\frac ba,&a<0, b>0\\
\end{cases}
$$

where $a=\text{Re }z,b=\text{Im }z$.

See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) for further information.